# cloud service for mobile application development

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, azure

I am starting a project to develop an application for WP7 and Android which uses Windows Azure cloud services. The cloud service periodically sends some data stored in its database to some of the registered mobile devices, based on some rules.

There should be a way to install a custom VM on Azure so that this VM can decide when to send data to which mobile device. With "Windows Azure Toolkit" it is possible for the mobile application to store data on Azure and retrieve the data later, but I can't see how it would be possible to leverage a VM installed on Azure using this toolkit.

Is this possible at all or not? If yes, from where I should start developing the application?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-dotnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I generally recommend using Mobile Services and the scenario you describe is relatively easy to accomplish with Mobile Services (You'd just write a server script in JavaScript that's triggered by a CRUD action or that's scheduled to run at a given time interval to users that meet certain criteria), unfortunately you're targeting two platforms that aren't officially supported at the moment.

There are unofficial SDKS available now that you could use if you'd like (and an official Android SDK is on the roadmap):

Android: https://github.com/goldshtn/wams-android

WP7: https://github.com/zaxy78/azure-mobile-wp7-sdk

You can also access the REST API directly here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx

Otherwise, you can always use Cloud Services, Microsoft's main PaaS offering.  You'd probably need a small worker role to accomplish what you detail above.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/mobile-services/)" are a collection of utilities that you don't need to manage and take away a lot of the hosting and configuration issues from you. They add features such as scalability, etc. but the down side is that you don't have as much control over them.

If you must have the code in a VM then you'll need to write it yourself. For Windows Phone you should have a look at [this helper library](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/14/windows-push-notification-server-side-helper-library.aspx).